# String.Replace method ignores case with special characters.

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string containing a server file path ($\MyPath\Quotas\ExactPath\MyFile.txt) and a local file system path (C:\MyLocalPath\Quotas\ExactPath).  I want to replace the server file path with the local system path.

I currently have an exact replace:

```
String fPath = @"$\MyPath\Quotas\ExactPath\MyFile.txt";
String sPath = @"$\MyPath\Quotas\ExactPath\";
String lPath = @"C:\MyLocalPath\Quotas\ExactPath\";

String newPath = fPath.Replace(sPath, lPath);
```

But I want this to be a case-insensitive replace, so that it would replace $\MyPath\quotas\Exactpath\ with lPath as well.

I came across the use of Regular Expressions like the following:

```
var regex = new Regex( sPath, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newFPath = regex.Replace( fPath, lPath );
```

But how do I handle the special characters ($,\,/,:) so that it is not interpreted as a regular expression special character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(sPath), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var newFPath = regex.Replace(fPath, lPath);
```

Comment: In the example with var regex and var newFPath, would I want to escape sPath, fPath, AND lPath, or just sPath?

Comment: @John, just the one you are using as regex - `sPath` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

```
fPath = Regex.Escape(fPath);
```

This escapes all metacharacters and turns them into literals.

Comment: In the example with var regex and var newFPath, would I want to escape sPath, fPath, AND lPath, or just fPath?

Comment: @John Escape the one you are using to construct your regex. So in your case you would escape `sPath`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are only after the case sensetivity setting, and not any regular expression matching, you should rather use `String.Replace` rather than `Regex.Replace`. Surprisingly enough there is no overload of the `Replace` method that takes any culture or comparison settings, but that can be fixed with an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions {

  public static string Replace(this string str, string match, string replacement, StringComparison comparison) {
    int index = 0, newIndex;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while ((newIndex = str.IndexOf(match, index, comparison)) != -1) {
      result.Append(str.Substring(index, newIndex - index)).Append(replacement);
      index = newIndex + match.Length;
    }
    return index > 0 ? result.Append(str.Substring(index)).ToString() : str;
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
String newPath = fPath.Replace(sPath, lPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Testing the performance, this shows to be 10-15 times faster than using `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using Replace at all.  Use the **Path** class in System.IO:

```
string fPath = @"$\MyPath\Quotas\ExactPath\MyFile.txt";
string lPath = @"C:\MyLocalPath\Quotas\ExactPath\";

string newPath = Path.Combine(lPath, Path.GetFileName(fPath));
```